# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 on mac

Tags: java, ios, macos

I am getting below issue while running scripts with iOS-driver on Mac machine
I am using JDK 1.8
Java –version commands output is:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I need java1.7 to run the iOS-driver (ref: https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/108).
I have followed below steps to change java version to 1.7
Installed JDK 1.7
Changed preference to jdk 1.7 in eclipse ide
Changed the environment veritable to point jdk 1.7.  Set java_home in ~/.bash_profile file.
But still I am facing same issue.
Could some one please help me resolving this issue on Mac OS.
Thank you.

Error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/mobile/tests/PPARegistrationthruMyeBay : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.forName(ClassHelper.java:96)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:78)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:504)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1370)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:815)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:744)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:128)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:543)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your runtime is 1.7 still your project is getting compiled with version 1.8. make sure that the compiler is set to 1.7

```
Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler
```

Comment: i have tried it, i have changed my compiler to 1.7. but i am still getting same errors.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you compile your program with a higher major version and try running it in a runtime environment of a lower major version. Here, you are compiling your program with Java-8, whereas you are running it in a Java-7 environment.

You need to either set the compiler version to Java-7 to match the runtime environment version, or you need to set your runtime version to Java-8 to match your compiler version.

Comment: i have tried it, i have changed my compiler to 1.7. but i am still getting same errors.

Comment: i have compiled and running my scripts on same machine with environment.

Comment: Try uninstalling JDK1.8 from your machine and see if that fixes it. Although, from your post you are saying that you have set the environment variable and changed the eclipse configuration, that should have done it. Did you restart your eclipse after changing the value of your environment variable? If not then you should do that. Eclipse will not read the updated environment variable unless it is restarted